# Hibernate Many to Many Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.k5008.hib2.Student.modules[com.k5008.hib2.Module]

Tags: hibernate

Please can someone advise, I am new to hibernate I cant figure out what is wrong.

error
Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class

I'll only show the code snippets which I think are important.

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        .....
        <mapping class="com.k5008.hib2.Module"/>  
        <mapping class="com.k5008.hib2.Student"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>

----
package com.k5008.hib2;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Module 
{
    @Id
    @Column (name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue    
    private int ID;
    @Column (name = "CODE")
    private String code;
    @Column (name = "NAME")
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "modules", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Student> students;

-----

package com.k5008.hib2;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;

@Entity
@Table (name ="STUDENT")
public class Student {
    @Id
    @Column (name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue
    private int ID;
    @Column (name = "NAME")
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(targetEntity=Module.class,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name="STUMOD",
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="STUID",referencedColumnName="ID")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="MODID",referencedColumnName="ID")}
    ) 
    private Set<Module> modules;

-------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE STUDENT
(
        ID INT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
        NAME VARCHAR(30), 
        PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
CREATE TABLE MODULE
(      ID INT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
       CODE VARCHAR(10), 
       NAME VARCHAR(50),        
       PRIMARY KEY (ID) 
);
CREATE TABLE STUMOD
(       
        STUID INT NOT NULL,
        MODID INT NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(STUID,MODID)
);
```

---

The error I am getting is the following

Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.k5008.hib2.Student.modules[com.k5008.hib2.Module]
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindManyToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1332)
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:870)

Comment: You need to put `@Entity` on top of `Module`...

Comment: Thank you very much. Solved :)